# How to make an Action Bar containing a title and 2 buttons?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to make an `Action Bar` like
[this one](http://www.androidside.com/docs/////resources/samples/images/ActionBarCompat1.png)

I tried the sample in the Android sdk but it's too complicated there are like 8 `.java` files for this Action Bar?

---

[image: ActionBarCompat]

---

I hope someone can provide me with an easier method and simpler way to do it. As I don't think i'm gonna copy all those 8 files to my project in order to make an `Action Bar` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approach.

Beginns add a meny layout in your res/menu folder
action_bar_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon1.png"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="One">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2.png"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Two">
    </item>

</menu>
```

in your activity

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("your title"); 
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    //actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  }


 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_one:
         //put your business logic here
         break;
      case R.id.action_two:
         //put your business logic here
         break;
     case android.R.id.home:
        //put your business logic here
     break;
      default:
         // Nothing to do here 
      }
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! what's getSupportMenuInflater()? i'm getting a compilation error

Comment: @JonathanHugh sorry this was my mistake. Do you have preferences about the actionbars? i just update my post

Comment: Force close :(.. The problem is in the onCreate() method

Comment: @JonathanHugh did you add a activity_main layout? and what did the logcat say?

Comment: i made a new project and it worked it seems like something is going wrong with my usual project... when i tried to test the app having the action bar you provided in an emulator running android 2.2 it force closed. will it work only for 3.0 and above? this is what it seems..

Comment: @JonathanHugh may be. i don't know exactly. It was tested under androi d 4 and more. May be you need to make some walk aroud to get it work on 2.2. If you like my answer just accept it and vote up. thanks